# Ways to load an external model using the THREE.BinaryLoader() in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader

I am making my first steps coding with JavaScript and playing with Three.js too.

I have this code to load a geometry using the Binary Loader:

```
loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
loader.load( "path/to/geometry.js", function ( geometry ) {

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.scale.set( 40, 40, 40 );
scene.add(mesh);

} );
```

But what about if I want to add `mesh` to the global scope? I made this code but it doesn't works:

```
loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
geometry = loader.load( "path/to/geometry.js");

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.scale.set( 40, 40, 40 );
scene.add(mesh);
```

Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You can't do that because `BinaryLoader.load` is asynchronous. And since you don't declare your variables with `var`, `mesh` was already in the global scope at the begining. The problem is that `mesh` is assigned later on, when the loading is finished.